# Remove null from unused space of StringArray when converting to a string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I was working on a Java coding problem and encountered the following issue.

```
Input: A String -> "Code"
Output Expected: A string -> CCoCodCode
```

My Code snippet: (Note: In comments I have written what I expect upon passing the string)

```
public String stringSplosion(String str) { // string Say 'Code'
    String join = "", values = "";
    String gotIt = "";

    int n = str.length(); // 4
    int size = 0;

    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
        size = size + n; // 4+3+2+1=10
    }

    String[] result = new String[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        values = str.substring(i, i + 1);
        join = join + values;
        result[i] = join;
    }

    for (String s : result) {
        gotIt = gotIt + s;
    }

    return gotIt; // Expected output: CCoCodCode
}
```

Output I am getting:

```
CCoCodCodenullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
```

Why is `null` getting stored although I have reduced the size and how can I remove it?

**NOTE:** I need to solve this using arrays. I know it is much easier using List.

Comment: Please learn how to enter code.  It's not hard, either indent 4 spaces or use the `{}` button in the embedded editor.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. I will follow it.

Comment: size is null because your array seems too big? why not only print the value if it is not null

Comment: @JohnKane array size is not big. I have used a for loop to exactly get the size of the result I want.

Comment: appreciate all the answers. understood my mistake in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size should be the length of string. Code's length is 4. Code will produce {C, Co, Cod, Code}.

```
  public String stringSplosion(String str) { // string Say 'Code'
    String join = "", values = "";
    String gotIt = "";

    int n = str.length(); // 4

    String[] result = new String[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        values = str.substring(i, i + 1);
        join = join + values;
        result[i] = join;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

    for (String s : result) {
        gotIt = gotIt + s;
    }

    return gotIt; // Expected output: CCoCodCode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Answer {

public static String answer(String input){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(((input.length() + 1) * input.length()) / 2);

    for (int i = 1; i <= input.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(input.substring(0, i));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(answer("Code"));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the current structure of your code, get rid of the first for loop.
And create String[] array = new String[n]

```
public static String stringSplosion(String str) { // string Say 'Code'
String join = "", values = "";
String gotIt = "";

int n = str.length(); // 4

String[] result = new String[n]; //you want your String array to contain 4 strings

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    values = str.substring(i, i + 1);
    join = join + values;
    result[i] = join;
}

for (String s : result) {
    gotIt = gotIt + s;
}

return gotIt; // Expected output: CCoCodCode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below statements are not required:

```
int size = 0;

    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
        size = size + n; // 4+3+2+1=10
    }
```

You just need to change the array size from

```
String[] result = new String[size];
```

to

```
String[] result = new String[n];
```

for your program to give the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand ur problem correctly to print the pattern then u can use below code,

```
public String printPattern(String input){    
//Holds the iteration value by index
int previous=0;
//It holds the result characters
String result=null;
StringBuilder strBuilder=new StringBuilder();
//first loop to iterate only till input string length
for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
    //checking iteration lenght with input string length 
    if(previous<input.length()){
        //incrementing iteration for reading characters from input string
        previous++;
        //main loop for previous iteration value check and iterate
        for(int j=0;j<previous;j++){
            //converting string to Character array
            char a []=input.toCharArray();
            //using string builder to build the string from characters
            strBuilder.append((a[j]));
            //setting the value to stringbuilder by converting it in string
            result=strBuilder.toString();

        }

    }
}

return result;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "Code";
String output[] = IntStream.range(0, input.length()+1)
            .mapToObj(i -> input.substring(0, i))
            .toArray(String[]::new);
```